# An example code from official website - Redirects (auth) - where to define the authentication state in practice?

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I am new to React Router and just started learning.
I was following the examples from the website, but I got stuck with this example https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow, since it was not working as expected.

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
  useHistory,
  useLocation
} from "react-router-dom";

// This example has 3 pages: a public page, a protected
// page, and a login screen. In order to see the protected
// page, you must first login. Pretty standard stuff.
//
// First, visit the public page. Then, visit the protected
// page. You're not yet logged in, so you are redirected
// to the login page. After you login, you are redirected
// back to the protected page.
//
// Notice the URL change each time. If you click the back
// button at this point, would you expect to go back to the
// login page? No! You're already logged in. Try it out,
// and you'll see you go back to the page you visited
// just *before* logging in, the public page.

export default function AuthExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <AuthButton />

        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/public">Public Page</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/protected">Protected Page</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/public">
            <PublicPage />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login">
            <LoginPage />
          </Route>
          <PrivateRoute path="/protected">
            <ProtectedPage />
          </PrivateRoute>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

const fakeAuth = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  authenticate(cb) {
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated = true;
    setTimeout(cb, 100); // fake async
  },
  signout(cb) {
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated = false;
    setTimeout(cb, 100);
  }
};

function AuthButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  return fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
    <p>
      Welcome!{" "}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          fakeAuth.signout(() => history.push("/"));
        }}
      >
        Sign out
      </button>
    </p>
  ) : (
    <p>You are not logged in.</p>
  );
}

// A wrapper for <Route> that redirects to the login
// screen if you're not yet authenticated.
function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

function PublicPage() {
  return <h3>Public</h3>;
}

function ProtectedPage() {
  return <h3>Protected</h3>;
}

function LoginPage() {
  let history = useHistory();
  let location = useLocation();

  let { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
  let login = () => {
    fakeAuth.authenticate(() => {
      history.replace(from);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You must log in to view the page at {from.pathname}</p>
      <button onClick={login}>Log in</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried it in the codesandbox in the website and also in local myself, but the `<AuthButton>` component doesn't seem to re-render such that after clicking the login button it still shows `<p>You are not logged in.</p>`, not the "Welcome! [Sign out button]". Does anyone know what the issue would be? I found this link https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7348 who was having the same issue as me, but I couldn't find any more information.

**EDIT:** I had first thought that I was missing something since I just believed that the example code would work in a correct way. Seems that it was not like that. So I tried to modify the code myself and came up with a working solution

https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-tdd-qus9g?file=/src/AuthWithRedirect.js

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Link,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
  useHistory,
  useLocation
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function AuthWithRedirect() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = React.useState(false);

  function authenticate(cb) {
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
    setTimeout(cb, 1000);
  }

  function signout(cb) {
    setIsAuthenticated(false);
    setTimeout(cb, 1000);
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <AuthButton signout={signout} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />

        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/public">Public Page</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/protected">Protected Page</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/public">
            <PublicPage />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login">
            <LoginPage authenticate={authenticate} />
          </Route>
          <PrivateRoute path="/protected" isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}>
            <ProtectedPage />
          </PrivateRoute>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function AuthButton({ isAuthenticated, signout }) {
  let history = useHistory();

  return isAuthenticated ? (
    <p>
      Welcome!{" "}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          signout(() => history.push("/"));
        }}
      >
        Sign out
      </button>
    </p>
  ) : (
    <p>You are not logged in.</p>
  );
}

// A wrapper for <Route> that redirects to the login screen
// if the user is not authenticated
function PrivateRoute({ children, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) => {
        return isAuthenticated ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}

function PublicPage() {
  return <h3>Public</h3>;
}

function ProtectedPage() {
  return <h3>Protected</h3>;
}

function LoginPage({ authenticate }) {
  let history = useHistory();
  let location = useLocation();

  let { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
  let login = () => {
    authenticate(() => {
      history.replace(from);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You must log in to view the page at {from.pathname}</p>
      <button onClick={login}>Log in</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Still, I'm wondering if this would be a standard, scalable way to handle the authentication state, which is kind of a global state throughout the app. Could anyone give a good source of example?

Answer (score 0):

1. `<AuthExample/>` and `<AuthButton/>` are stateless components
2. React needs `setState()` to trigger rendering
3. I think this is no problem

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Then how should one modify and structure the code, (In which component to define the state) in this kind of authentication workflow?